# Flash external window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I Flash TaskBar icon of external application? I have tried FlashWindowEx and checked it out onpInvoke.net and also http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/01/26/CSharp-Flash-Window-in-Taskbar-via-Win32-FlashWindowEx but that only deals with flashing the current Form (this). I can't make it Flash an external window though.

I have got a hWnd (IntPtr) and also a process.MainWindowHandle to the external app that I want to flash, but I don't know how to use FlashWindowEx to flash the external window.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `FlashWindowEx`, just pass the MainWindowHandle of the other application you want to flash. For example, you can use the `FlashOtherWindow` function shown below, passing in the handle.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool FlashWindowEx(ref FLASHWINFO pwfi);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FLASHWINFO
    {
        public UInt32 cbSize;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public UInt32 dwFlags;
        public UInt32 uCount;
        public UInt32 dwTimeout;
    }

    internal static void FlashOtherWindow(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        FLASHWINFO fInfo = new FLASHWINFO();
        fInfo.cbSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(fInfo));
        fInfo.dwFlags = 2;
        fInfo.dwTimeout = 0;
        fInfo.hwnd = windowHandle;
        fInfo.uCount = 3;

        FlashWindowEx(ref fInfo);
    }

    internal static void FlashApplicationWindow(string application)
    {
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(application))
            FlashOtherWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
    }
```

I also included `FlashApplicationWindow` that takes the name of the application. You can use it like so:

```
    FlashApplicationWindow("firefox");
```